# Linux kernel module reference counter is always zero

Tags: module, reference, kernel, counter, procfs

I am implementing a kernel module that exposes some data to userspase using mmap interface.

I create a file in /proc file system passing struct file_operations with pointers to needed functions:

```
static struct file_operations module_file_ops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = module_open,
    .mmap = module_mmap
};

proc_create(THIS_MODULE->name, 0444, NULL, &module_file_ops);
```

Userspace application is able to open and read from the file (mmap contents) as expected.

When I do lsof I see the file is opened by the userspace app.

However, lsmod always gives zero as usage counter despite I set .owner to THIS_MODULE, so that I can easily remove the module with rmmod and lead the system to crash.

Please advise.

---

**module.c**

```
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>

static struct proc_dir_entry *proc_file;

static const struct file_operations test_file_ops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE
};

static int __init initialize(void) {
    int error = 0;

    proc_file = proc_create(THIS_MODULE->name, 0444, NULL, &test_file_ops);
    if (!proc_file) {
        error = -EIO;
    }

    return error;
}

static void __exit teardown(void) {
    proc_remove(proc_file);
}

module_init(initialize);
module_exit(teardown);
```

**Makefile**

```
obj-m += test.o
test-objs := module.o

CC=gcc
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu

all:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

Comment: Which Linux kernel version do you use? In new kernels the function `proc_create` accepts operations as `struct proc_ops`, not as `struct file_operations`.

Comment: 3.10.0 and compiler doesn't issue any warnings. Note I am not calling try_module_get /  module_put explicitly, may be I should?

Comment: With given kernel it should work without explicit `try_module_get` and `module_put`. That is, the module should be prevented from unload while the file is opened (`open()` without `close()`). "so that I can easily remove the module with rmmod and lead the system to crash." - Have your **actually** tried that and actually observed **crash** in the kernel (not in the user)? Please, show more complete code of your module (preferably as [mcve]).

Comment: Yes, I tried - kernel crash. I updated the question with the example. When I run test program that does open("/proc/test", O_RDONLY); then sleep(1000000); I see the file in lsof, but lsmod gives zero as the third field. Please advise.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Btw, you are saying that "In new kernels the function proc_create accepts operations as struct proc_ops, not as struct file_operations.", but proc_ops doesn't have **owner** field, so maybe not increasing ref counter is expected for procfs eventually?

Comment: Do you have solutions? I'm having the same issue here.

Comment: @Xingx1 , well, I ended up with try_module_get / module_put manual calls...